# Programmatically check profile login hours

Tags: apex, profile

I need to create a routine that records the accumulated amount of time spent by the user when he changes the case status from A to B, but i need to take in account the login hours of his profile to get the real spent time to treat the case.

My question is, is possible to programatically check the login hours configured in his profile to do the correct calculations?

If so, in which object it would be available to use in apex?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this information is stored under a table called LoginHours. This Sobject is currently not accessible via Apex. I would recommend storing this information somewhere else in Salesforce (maybe custom setting or new Sobject) so you can query out later and do your proper logic against.